# Vaadin grid-renderers-collection-addon breaks compilation of widgetset

Tags: compilation, widget, vaadin

I added grid-renderers-collection-addon to my pom.xml in a maven project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>grid-renderers-collection-addon</artifactId>
    <version>0.94</version>
</dependency>
```

Now everything is broken, even if I remove the addon from pom.xml again.
I get the message:

```
Failed to load the widgetset: ./../../VAADIN/widgetsets/AppWidgetset/AppWidgetset.nocache.js?1519127577157
```

I really want to use the addon, but I don't even know which is the latest version. I looked at solutions that involved having a ProjectWidgetSet.gwt.xml file, but I don't know where to get this file from.

vaadin.version is 8.1.1 not sure the addon is matching this version

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the error by commenting out an important artifact in pom.xml, launching the service (aborting because of errors), then adding the artifact again.
It was this artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```